# Pending message in weblogic 10.3.3?

Tags: jms, weblogic

I'm using weblogic 10.3.3, when I sends messages to Queue then its going in pending messsage which should in current message. I'm using code :

```
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
//.....

qSession = qConnect.createQueueSession(
            false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

//.....

TextMessage tmsg= qSession.createTextMessage();
tmsg.setText(message);

QueueSender qSender = qSession.createSender(requestQ);
qSender.send(tmsg);
```

I have gone through google but not found the helpful solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [manual entry](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JMSjmsservermonitordestinationstitle.html),

> A pending message is one that has either been sent in a transaction
>   and not committed, or that has been received and not committed or
>   acknowledged.

As you're using AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE, I guess either you're sending messages in a transaction that has not been committed or message processing takes so long that it is still in process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response . I understood the root cause.